# Two modules overriding same files.How to make sure they work correctly?

Tags: checkout, magento-1, template, overrides, conflict

I have two modules installed in my store they both override **billing.phtml** and **shipping.phtml** due to which some steps in my checkout are missing OR say they are not functioning correctly.How can i fix this?

Comment: Are these two modules in same code pool? local or community?

Comment: @Muk No not in same.One is in community one in local

Comment: @Fufu Tala, can you give more details.  What are the exact paths of the files which the modules are using.  What Theme package are you using, it sounds like something which could be fixed with the template fallback method.  You may have to write your own template for both these files

Comment: @FufuTulla, also turn on [Template Path Hints](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#configuration/advanced/developer.html) to find out exactly which template files (.phtml) are being called.

Comment: @CreedBratton both of my modules in app/design/frontend/base/default are lik : module-A/ onepage/billing.phtml + shipping.html  AND module-B/onepage/billing.phtml + shipping.phtml

Comment: @FufuTulla, that doesn't make sense.  Template files are kept in the design directory, i.e. `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml`.  Update it in your question, have you turned on template path hints to see which template file is being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am assuming that there is no block rewrite conflict, or if there is, the only thing the block classes do is change the path to the templates.**

Diff both against the versions in `base/default` to find out what has been added and changed.

Find out, which of the templates get used. Usually this is the one that comes later alphabetically, but to be sure inspect the HTML in your browser or activate template hints.

Then make copies of these and apply the changes from the other module manually. If you have a single theme, you can put these copies in your theme directory. Otherwise I'd recommend to move them to a new path within `base/default`, create a new module that `<depends>` on both existing modules (to make sure it is loaded last) and sets the templates to the new paths.